# Why did Lovett, McCloy and Bundy want to resign from their US cabinet positions in September 1945?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, political-history, asia, foreign-policy

Why did

- Robert Lovett (Assistant Secretary of War for Air)
- John J. McCloy (of the War
  Department)
- Harvey Hollister Bundy (liaison to the Office of
  Scientific Research and Development)

want to resign their positions in September 1945?

The context from my perspective is I am researching why the United States created the policy they did after WWII.

In this case I am looking at the so-called "wise men" Acheson, Kennan, Harriman, McCloy, Lovett and Bohlen who came up with the policy of containment with regard to dealing with the USSR.

McCloy and Lovett were the only Republicans and I wonder if their earlier threat to resign along with Bundy had something to do with President Truman's initial policies. Source is the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Lovett#Politics) page on  Robert A. Lovett under Politics.

Comment: The war was over. There were other jobs to get back to. Given that their resignations were refused by Truman, and, say, Lovett served under Truman’s administration, internal rifts seem unlikely. The (bipartisan) war ended, offer to resign to allow the administration to structure as they wished. Truman kept them on.

Comment: Sorry does not answer the question. I am looking for the specific reason for their desire to resign at the same time. Remember this is when the Roosevelt and Truman regimes were already begining to take the heat of their direct role in handing China to the Communists. Also the defection of Igor Gouzenko who had information on the Roosevelt and Truman regime they did not want getting out. Was any of this a catalyst for their desire to leave. Remember it was Lovett and McCloy that originally followed suit with Kennan and Bohlen to adopt the useless and murderous Containment policy.

Comment: I agree it is not a full answer, but FDR did bring a number of Republicans into his wartime cabinet to make it more bipartisan. Those folks knew full well that they had their position because of that, and once the war was over their presence was no longer needed for bipartisanship and the 'decent' thing to do was offer to leave. Different times.

Comment: Would those specific individuals have even bothered to tell people why they wanted to resign, and would records have been kept?

Comment: Re: McCloy - his Wikipedia page includes ‘ Without regard to partisanship, he served under presidents of both parties. Although a Republican, he was the second-highest ranking official in the War Department during World War II. Like his fellow “Wise Men,” McCloy often heeded the call to service. Despite having lucrative jobs on Wall Street, he left his positions to serve in government, whether to serve in the War Department or as the High Commissioner in Germany.’

Comment: Ok, thanks for your efforts.  I have consulted the Truman Library, Lovett and McCloy papers and hopefully I will get a definite answer from those institutions. However with this Covid-19 mess I do not anticipate an answer anytime soon.

Comment: BTW- FDR's effort to be bipartisan has been revealed to be not what it seems. This is part of the reason I am so suspicious. A few resigned at the end of the war due to Roosevelt's pro-USSR and Communist Chinese policies to include his Ambassador to China. There was a major effort to cover all that up.